# Get substring up until the first question mark

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a string which I have stored in a variable called `OriginalURL`. Its basically like this:

```
<cfset OriginalURL = StructFind(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'X-Original-URL')/>
```

All its doing is checking what the URL is in the browser and storing that as the value. A typical value would be something like `website.com/make/volvo/model/xc90?Page=2`

What I want to do is extract everything start from the left of the string up until it reaches the first `?` question mark. So it would extract just this part `website.com/make/volvo/model/xc90`

I'm not sure how to do a `Left()` statement using Regex so that it only matches up to the first question mark.

Comment: Psst... think list functions. A CF "list" is just a string delimited by an arbitrary character(s).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The very quick and simple answer to this is to just use the list functions with a delimiter, as there can be only one.

```
ListFirst(OriginalURL,'?')
```

Will give you everything before the ?

```
ListLast(OriginalURL,'?')
```

Will get you everything after the ?

Answer (score 2):

`ListFirst()` is probably the easiest way of doing this. But if you want to use a regular expression then you might try the following

```
REReplace(OriginalURL, "\?.*$", "")
```

which will replace the question mark and everything following it with nothing. You could also use `REMatch()` as follows:

```
REMatch("^[^\?]*", OriginalURL)[1]
```

(`REMatch()` returns an array so in this case we want to get the first element of that array.)

Hope this helps.